# Update CEWP without refreshing page

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, content-editor-web-part, refresh

I have a webpart which contains 3 charts. The charts are built using google's chart API and [SPJS Chart](http://spjsblog.com/2012/02/03/spjs-charts-for-sharepoint-v3-x/)

The problem I face is that I'm trying to get the charts to seamlessly update as the list gets populated. However, I'm not looking to refresh the entire page, just the charts. Any idea how this could be accomplished?

What would be best is if the list changes could trigger the refresh as oppose to an interval refresh but I'm willing to try any solution and see what works best.

Comment: I'm going to throw this in as a comment, as it isn't a direct answer - take a look at this topic on [JQuery AJAX Polling Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941123/jquery-ajax-polling-syntax). I struggled with updating a chart last year and this was my solution; I placed my rendering instructions inside of the success function. Hope this helps!